# Parsing nested arrays in Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

Im struggling to parse the below JSON using the Aeson library.
Im only interested in getting file1 but I cant seem to manage it.
Does anyone have suggestions?

**The JSON**

```
{"files":[["file1.wav",["file2.jpg","file3.jpg"]]]}
```

**My code**

```
data File = File Text deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON)

instance FromJSON File where
  parseJSON jsn = do
    arrays <- parseJSON jsn
    let x = arrays !! 0 !! 0
    return $ File x
```

**Error message**

```
"Error in $.files[0][1]: parsing Text failed, expected String, but encountered Array"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using `parseJSON` to parse `jsn` into a *homogeneous* list. But `"file1.wav"` is a string and `["file2.jpg", "file3.jpg"]` is not a string.

A simple solution is to directly pattern-match on `json`, which is a [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value) which can contain a heterogeneous `Array` (in spite of its name, it's actually a synonym for a `Vector` from the *vector* library).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Text (Text)

newtype File = File Text deriving Show

instance FromJSON File where
  parseJSON json = do
    Array arr <- pure json
    Just (Array arr0) <- pure (arr V.!? 0)
    Just (String txt) <- pure (arr0 V.!? 0)
    pure (File txt)

main :: IO ()
main = print (decode' "[[\"file1\", [\"file2\", \"file3\"]]]" :: Maybe File)
```

([`(!?)` is a safe indexing operator.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:-33--63-))

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! When trying to compile your code it complained about  "Just" so I removed them both and then it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I was looking for a total version of `head` but then I got distracted. I've just fixed it by using `(!?)`, but dropping `Just` as you said also works.

Comment: Thanks I didn’t know about the safe indexing operator!